# checking for equality on dispatch_queue_t

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch, nsthread

How can I check for equality between dispatch_queue_t vars?

```
dispatch_queue_t currentQueue = dispatch_get_current_queue();
dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
if (currentQueue == mainQueue) {

}
```

from the docs:

```
typedef struct dispatch_queue_s *dispatch_queue_t;
```

I'm not sure but does this mean that it's a pointer to a dispatch_queue_s struct?

Since I can't check equality on pointers, I'm not sure how can I check if a dispatch_queue_t is the same as another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the queue you're on. In this particular case use:

```
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {}
```

In general, you can use `dispatch_get_current_queue()` to test which queue your're on. In that case you can use the `==` operator to do so. To quote the Dispatch Queues page in Apple's Concurrency Programming Guide:

> Use the dispatch_get_current_queue function for debugging purposes or
>   to test the identity of the current queue. Calling this function from
>   inside a block object returns the queue to which the block was
>   submitted (and on which it is now presumably running). Calling this
>   function from outside of a block returns the default concurrent queue
>   for your application.

Comment: That quote does say that you can use `dispatch_get_current_queue` “ to test the identity of the current queue”. The catch is that it only works as expected within a dispatched block.

Answer (score 24):

Since **dispatch_get_current_queue()** is deprecated, we could compare current and your queues by their labels (or specifics as @jkh suggested)

For label use

```
dispatch_queue_get_label(dispatch_queue_t queue);
```

and pass DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL for get label of current queue

For specific:

```
dispatch_queue_get_specific(dispatch_queue_t queue, const void *key);
```

for get you queue specific and

```
dispatch_get_specific(const void *key);
```

for current

It's require to set one or both of label and specific for your queue. 
For example when you create it

```
dispatch_queue_create(const char *label, dispatch_queue_attr_t attr);
```

or using setters for specific

```
dispatch_queue_set_specific(dispatch_queue_t queue, const void *key,
    void *context, dispatch_function_t destructor);
```

Comment: This was a huge help. I used `dispatch_queue_set_specific` with a simple boolean flag when I created my queue and `dispatch_get_specific` to see if that flag was set. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Is there an advantage to using one or the other (label or specific)?

Comment: @AlfieHanssen not sure 100% but think that there is no much performance difference, ok to use what is much convenient for you

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea about `DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL`, the docs don't mention it. In fact, the docs says `queue` can't be `NULL`, but the header file says `DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL` is a valid argument for `queue`, and defines it as `NULL`...

Answer (score 2):

First part of answer:  What are you trying to do?  Why do you need to compare queues?  If all you need to do is "tag" a queue with some specific piece of metadata, consider using dispatch_queue_{set, get}_specific() instead.

Second part of answer:  Don't use dispatch_get_current_queue() for, well, anything.  It's just for debugging purposes and its use has always been discouraged.

Comment: Would this be why `dispatch_get_current_queue()` is marked as deprecated in the iOS 6.0 headers (although oddly not in the Mountain Lion ones)? I had been using it in a wrapper function to run a block synchronously on a serial queue, but not deadlock if that function happened to be called from within that queue itself. I had assumed that we could use it to perform a check of the identity of the dispatch queue that the function was called from. I take it that's not a safe practice?

Comment: That's not a safe practice in general, because queue A could make a synchronous dispatch into queue B, which could then try to dispatch back into queue A, and that approach wouldn't detect the deadlock.