# Callback to CFNetwork thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

From the CFNetwork thread, I'd like to do some processing on the main queue, and get the result asynchronously. Right now, I'm dispatching the results to the queue obtained with `dispatch_get_current_queue` to get the results back.

```
dispatch_queue_t baseQueue = dispatch_get_current_queue();
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSString* content = [self processSomething];
    dispatch_async(baseQueue, ^{
        [self sendResults:result];
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, `dispatch_get_current_queue` is deprecated. How can I achieve the same thing without using `dispatch_get_current_queue`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternatives to dispatch\_get\_current\_queue() for completion blocks in iOS 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237417/alternatives-to-dispatch-get-current-queue-for-completion-blocks-in-ios-6)

Answer (score 1):

CFNetwork is run-loop based. To achieve what you're asking, you can use the `CFRunLoop` API. Like this:

```
// ...from some code called by CFNetwork on its run loop
CFRunLoop cfNetworkRunLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // On the main thread...
    NSString* content = [self processSomething];

    CFRunLoopPerformBlock(cfNetworkRunLoop, kCFRunLoopCommonModes, ^{
        // Back on CFNetwork's run loop
        [self sendResults:result];
    });
    // Necessary for your block to run right away, otherwise it might 
    // be delayed (until something else wakes up the run loop.)
    CFRunLoopWakeUp(cfNetworkRunLoop);
});
```

Hope that helps.