# GCD: how to check if two dispatch_queue_t is the same queue?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

```
dispatch_queue_t queue1 = /*some queue*/;
dispatch_queue_t queue2 = /*some queue*/;
```

how do I know if queue1 is the same queue with queue2?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606158/checking-for-equality-on-dispatch-queue-t

Comment: @tkanzakic thanks dude, I've tried that and it works.